# I can't draw my figure while moving camera in Web Gl

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I'm doing a project that I have to move a camera with an object in the scene. I can move the camera correctly in the scene. However there's not the object.

I don't understand which is the error because I transform the object and then I multiply that matrix with the camera matrix and I think it's the steps I have to follow.

Hope you can help me.

```js
const {mat4} = glMatrix;

var examplePlane = {  // 4 vértices, 2 triángulos

    "vertices" : [-0.5, 0.0, 0.5,
                   0.5, 0.0, 0.5,
                   0.5, 0.0,-0.5,
                  -0.5, 0.0,-0.5],
    
    "indices" : [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3]

};
  
var exampleCube = {  // 8 vértices, 12 triángulos
    
    "vertices" : [-0.5,-0.5,  0.5,
                   0.5,-0.5,  0.5,
                   0.5, 0.5,  0.5,
                  -0.5, 0.5,  0.5,
                  -0.5,-0.5, -0.5,
                   0.5,-0.5, -0.5,
                   0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
                  -0.5, 0.5, -0.5],

    "indices" : [ 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 
                  1, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2,
                  3, 2, 6, 3, 6, 7,
                  5, 4, 7, 5, 7, 6,
                  4, 0, 3, 4, 3, 7,
                  4, 5, 1, 4, 1, 0]

};

var exampleCover = {  // 13 vértices, 12 triángulos

    "vertices" : [ 1,  0, 0,  0.866,  0.5,   0,  0.5,    0.866, 0, 
                   0,  1, 0, -0.5,    0.866, 0, -0.86,   0.5,   0, 
                  -1,  0, 0, -0.866, -0.5,   0, -0.5,   -0.866, 0, 
                   0, -1, 0,  0.5,   -0.866, 0,  0.866, -0.5,   0, 
                   0,  0, 0],
                     
    "indices" : [ 0, 1, 12, 1, 2, 12, 2, 3, 12, 3,  4, 12,  4,  5, 12,  5, 6, 12,  
                  6, 7, 12, 7, 8, 12, 8, 9, 12, 9, 10, 12, 10, 11, 12, 11, 0, 12]

};

var exampleCone = {  // 13 vértices, 12 triángulos

    "vertices" : [ 1,  0, 0,  0.866,  0.5,   0,  0.5,    0.866, 0, 
                   0,  1, 0, -0.5,    0.866, 0, -0.86,   0.5,   0, 
                  -1,  0, 0, -0.866, -0.5,   0, -0.5,   -0.866, 0, 
                   0, -1, 0,  0.5,   -0.866, 0,  0.866, -0.5,   0, 
                   0,  0, 1],
                     
    "indices" : [ 0, 1, 12, 1, 2, 12, 2, 3, 12, 3,  4, 12,  4,  5, 12,  5, 6, 12,  
                  6, 7, 12, 7, 8, 12, 8, 9, 12, 9, 10, 12, 10, 11, 12, 11, 0, 12]

};
                    
var exampleCylinder = {  // 24 vértices, 24 triángulos

    "vertices" : [ 1,  0, 0,  0.866,  0.5,   0,  0.5,    0.866, 0, 
                   0,  1, 0, -0.5,    0.866, 0, -0.86,   0.5,   0, 
                  -1,  0, 0, -0.866, -0.5,   0, -0.5,   -0.866, 0, 
                   0, -1, 0,  0.5,   -0.866, 0,  0.866, -0.5,   0,
                   1,  0, 1,  0.866,  0.5,   1,  0.5,    0.866, 1, 
                   0,  1, 1, -0.5,    0.866, 1, -0.86,   0.5,   1, 
                  -1,  0, 1, -0.866, -0.5,   1, -0.5,   -0.866, 1, 
                   0, -1, 1,  0.5,   -0.866, 1,  0.866, -0.5,   1],
    
    "indices" : [ 0,  1, 12, 1,  2, 13, 2,  3, 14,  3,  4, 15,  4,  5, 16,  5,  6, 17,  
                  6,  7, 18, 7,  8, 19, 8,  9, 20,  9, 10, 21, 10, 11, 22, 11,  0, 23,
                  1, 13, 12, 2, 14, 13, 3, 15, 14,  4, 16, 15,  5, 17, 16,  6, 18, 17,
                  7, 19, 18, 8, 20, 19, 9, 21, 20, 10, 22, 21, 11, 23, 22,  0, 12, 23]

};
           
var exampleSphere = {  // 42 vértices, 80 triángulos

    "vertices" : [ 0.000000, 0.850651, 0.525731,
                  -0.309017, 0.500000, 0.809017,
                   0.309017, 0.500000, 0.809017,
                  -0.525731, 0.000000, 0.850651,
                   0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000,
                   0.525731, 0.000000, 0.850651,
                  -0.850651, 0.525731, 0.000000,
                  -0.809017, 0.309017, 0.500000,
                  -0.500000, 0.809017, 0.309017,
                   0.000000, 0.850651,-0.525731,
                  -0.500000, 0.809017,-0.309017,
                   0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000,
                   0.500000, 0.809017,-0.309017,
                   0.500000, 0.809017, 0.309017,
                   0.850651, 0.525731, 0.000000,
                   0.809017, 0.309017, 0.500000,
                   0.850651,-0.525731, 0.000000,
                   1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                   0.809017,-0.309017, 0.500000,
                   0.525731, 0.000000,-0.850651,
                   0.809017, 0.309017,-0.500000,
                   0.809017,-0.309017,-0.500000,
                   0.309017, 0.500000,-0.809017,
                  -0.525731, 0.000000,-0.850651,
                  -0.309017, 0.500000,-0.809017,
                   0.000000, 0.000000,-1.000000,
                   0.000000,-0.850651,-0.525731,
                  -0.309017,-0.500000,-0.809017,
                   0.309017,-0.500000,-0.809017,
                   0.500000,-0.809017,-0.309017,
                   0.000000,-0.850651, 0.525731,
                   0.000000,-1.000000, 0.000000,
                   0.500000,-0.809017, 0.309017,
                  -0.850651,-0.525731, 0.000000,
                  -0.500000,-0.809017,-0.309017,
                  -0.500000,-0.809017, 0.309017,
                  -0.809017,-0.309017, 0.500000,
                  -0.309017,-0.500000, 0.809017,
                   0.309017,-0.500000, 0.809017,
                  -1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                  -0.809017,-0.309017,-0.500000,
                  -0.809017, 0.309017,-0.500000],

    "indices" : [ 1, 2, 0, 4, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 2, 1, 7, 8, 6, 1, 7, 3, 8, 1, 0, 1, 8, 7,10,11, 9, 8,10, 6,
                 11, 8, 0, 8,11,10,11,12, 9,13,11, 0,12,13,14,13,12,11,13,15,14, 2,13, 0,15, 2, 5, 2,15,13,
                 17,18,16,15,17,14,18,15, 5,15,18,17,20,21,19,17,20,14,21,17,16,17,21,20,22,20,19,12,22, 9,
                 20,12,14,12,20,22,24,25,23,22,24, 9,25,22,19,22,25,24,27,28,26,25,27,23,28,25,19,25,28,27,
                 29,21,16,28,29,26,21,28,19,28,21,29,31,32,30,29,31,26,32,29,16,29,32,31,34,35,33,31,34,26,
                 35,31,30,31,35,34,36,37, 3,35,36,33,37,35,30,35,37,36, 4,38, 5,37, 4, 3,38,37,30,37,38, 4,
                 38,18, 5,32,38,30,18,32,16,32,18,38, 7,36, 3,39, 7, 6,36,39,33,39,36, 7,39,40,33,41,39, 6,
                 40,41,23,41,40,39,41,24,23,10,41, 6,24,10, 9,10,24,41,27,40,23,34,27,26,40,34,33,34,40,27]

};

function makeTorus (innerRadius, outerRadius, nSides, nRings) {
        
  var torus = {
      "vertices" : [],
      "indices"  : []
  };
  
  if (nSides < 3 ) nSides = 3;
  if (nRings < 3 ) nRings = 3;
        
  var dpsi =  2.0 * Math.PI / nRings ;
  var dphi = -2.0 * Math.PI / nSides ;
  var psi  =  0.0;
  
  for (var j = 0; j < nRings; j++) {
    
    var cpsi = Math.cos ( psi ) ;
    var spsi = Math.sin ( psi ) ;
    var phi  = 0.0;

    for (var i = 0; i < nSides; i++) {
      
      var offset = 3 * ( j * (nSides+1) + i ) ;
      var cphi   = Math.cos ( phi ) ;
      var sphi   = Math.sin ( phi ) ;
      
      torus.vertices[offset + 0] = cpsi * ( outerRadius + cphi * innerRadius ) ;
      torus.vertices[offset + 1] = spsi * ( outerRadius + cphi * innerRadius ) ;
      torus.vertices[offset + 2] =                        sphi * innerRadius   ;
      
      phi += dphi;
      
    }

    var offset = torus.vertices.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      torus.vertices[offset + i] = torus.vertices[offset-nSides*3+i];

    psi += dpsi;
    
  }

  var offset = torus.vertices.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < 3*(nSides+1); i++)
    torus.vertices[offset+i] = torus.vertices[i];

  for (var j = 0; j < nRings; j++){
    
    var desp = j * (nSides + 1);

    for (var i = 0; i < nSides; i++){
      
      torus.indices.push(desp + i,     desp + i + 1,              desp + i + (nSides+1)); 
      torus.indices.push(desp + i + 1, desp + i + (nSides+1) + 1, desp + i + (nSides+1)); 
      
    }
    
  }

  return torus; 
  
}


var gl, program;
var myTorus;
var myZeta = 0.0, myPhi = Math.PI/2.0, radius = 1.4, fovy = 1.4;

function getWebGLContext() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

  try {
    return canvas.getContext("webgl2",{antialias:true});
  }
  catch(e) {
  }

  return null;

}

function initShaders() {
    
  var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, document.getElementById("myVertexShader").text);
  gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
    return null;
  }
 
  var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, document.getElementById("myFragmentShader").text);
  gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
    return null;
  }
  
  program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  
  gl.linkProgram(program);
    
  gl.useProgram(program);
  idMyColor = gl.getUniformLocation (program, "myColor" );
  program.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "VertexPosition");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.vertexPositionAttribute);

  program.modelViewMatrixIndex  = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"modelViewMatrix");
  program.projectionMatrixIndex = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"projectionMatrix");

}

function initRendering() {

  gl.clearColor(0.95,0.95,0.95,1.0);
  gl.lineWidth(1.5);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

}

function initBuffers(model) {
    
  model.idBufferVertices = gl.createBuffer ();
  gl.bindBuffer (gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, model.idBufferVertices);
  gl.bufferData (gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(model.vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    
  model.idBufferIndices = gl.createBuffer ();
  gl.bindBuffer (gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.idBufferIndices);
  gl.bufferData (gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(model.indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

}

function draw(model) {
  console.log(model);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, model.idBufferVertices);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.idBufferIndices);
  for (var i = 0; i < model.indices.length; i += 3)
    // Si paint es true vol dir que volem pintar per tant farem el triangle_fan

    gl.drawElements (gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 3, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, i*2);
}

// set projection (apliquem una projecció al dibuix)
function setProjection() {
    
  // obtiene la matriz de transformación de la proyección perspectiva
  var projectionMatrix  = mat4.create();
  // perspective
  mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix, Math.PI/4.0, 1., 0.1, 100.0);
  
  // envía la matriz de transformación de la proyección al shader de vértices
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.projectionMatrixIndex,false,projectionMatrix);
}

function initPrimitives() {

  initBuffers(examplePlane);
  initBuffers(exampleCube);
  initBuffers(exampleCover);
  initBuffers(exampleCone);
  initBuffers(exampleCylinder);
  initBuffers(exampleSphere);

  myTorus = makeTorus(0.4, 1.0, 8, 12);
  initBuffers(myTorus);
  
}

function getCameraMatrix() {
  // coordenadas esféricas a rectangulares: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system
  var x = radius * Math.sin(myPhi) * Math.sin(myZeta);
  var y = radius * Math.cos(myPhi);
  var z = radius * Math.sin(myPhi) * Math.cos(myZeta);

  return mat4.lookAt(mat4.create(), [x, y, z], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]);
    
}


////////////////////
// move the Eye
////////////////////
var eye = [0, 0, 1.4];
var center = [0, 0, 0];

function moveEye () {
    
    return mat4.lookAt(mat4.create(), eye,  center, [0, 1, 0]);
}
///////////////////
///////////////////

function start_draw(model, rx, ry, rz, r1x, r1y, r1z, sx, sy, sz, tx, ty, tz, c1, c2, c3, c4){
  
  // 1. calcula la matriz de transformación
  var modelMatrix = mat4.create();
  var rotationmatr = mat4.create();
  var rotation2 = mat4.create();
  var transmatr = mat4.create();
  var scalematr = mat4.create();

  mat4.fromRotation (rotationmatr, Math.PI/2, [rx, ry, rz]);
  mat4.fromRotation (rotation2, Math.PI/2, [r1x, r1y, r1z]);
  mat4.fromScaling (scalematr, [sx, sy, sz]);
  mat4.multiply (modelMatrix, rotationmatr, rotation2);
  mat4.fromTranslation(transmatr,[tx, ty, tz]);
  mat4.multiply(modelMatrix, transmatr, modelMatrix);
  mat4.multiply(modelMatrix, modelMatrix, scalematr);

  var modelMatrixM     = mat4.create();
  var modelViewMatrixM = mat4.create();
  mat4.fromScaling(modelMatrixM, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]);

  mat4.multiply(modelViewMatrixM, moveEye(), modelMatrixM);
  mat4.multiply(modelViewMatrixM, getCameraMatrix(), modelViewMatrixM);

  var finalProj = mat4.create();
  mat4.multiply(finalProj, modelViewMatrixM, modelMatrix);

  // 2. establece la matriz modelMatrix en el shader de vértices
  console.log(finalProj);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.modelMatrixIndex, false, finalProj);

  gl.uniform4f (idMyColor, c1, c2, c3, c4);
  setProjection();
  draw(model);

}

function drawall(){


  start_draw(exampleCylinder, .5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, .1, .1, .6, -.6, .1, -3, .5, 0, .5, .7);
  
}

function drawScene() {
    
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  drawall();

}

function initHandlers() {
    
  var mouseDown = false;
  var lastMouseX;
  var lastMouseY;

  var canvas     = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var htmlPhi    = document.getElementById("Phi");
  var htmlZeta   = document.getElementById("Zeta");
  var htmlRadius = document.getElementById("Radius");
  var htmlFovy   = document.getElementById("Fovy");

  htmlPhi.innerHTML    = (myPhi  * 180 / Math.PI).toFixed(1);
  htmlZeta.innerHTML   = (myZeta * 180 / Math.PI).toFixed(1);
  htmlRadius.innerHTML = radius.toFixed(1);
  htmlFovy.innerHTML   = (fovy * 180 / Math.PI).toFixed(1);

 
  canvas.addEventListener("wheel",
    function (event) {
      
      var delta = 0.0;

      if (event.deltaMode == 0)
        delta = event.deltaY * 0.001;
      else if (event.deltaMode == 1)
        delta = event.deltaY * 0.03;
      else
        delta = event.deltaY;

      if (event.shiftKey == 1) { // fovy
          
        fovy *= Math.exp(-delta)
        fovy = Math.max (0.1, Math.min(3.0, fovy));
        
        htmlFovy.innerHTML = (fovy * 180 / Math.PI).toFixed(1);
        
      } else {
        
        radius *= Math.exp(-delta);
        radius  = Math.max(Math.min(radius, 30), 0.05);
        
        htmlRadius.innerHTML = radius.toFixed(1);
        
      }
      
      event.preventDefault();
      requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);

    }, false);
  
}        

function handleKeyDown(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
  switch (event.keyCode) {

    //MOVEMENT
    case 87: // ’w’ key
        eye[2] -= 0.01;
        center[2] -=0.01;
      break;
      // right
    case 83: // ’s’ key
      eye[2] += 0.01;
      center[2] +=0.01;

      break;
    case 65: // ’a’ key
      eye[0] -= 0.01;
      center[0] -=0.01;

      break;
      // right
    case 68: // ’d’ key
      eye[0] += 0.01;
      center[0] +=0.01;
      break;

    //CAMERA MOVEMENT
    case 38: // ’up arrow’ key
      myPhi+=0.01;
    break;
    // right
    
    case 40: // ’down arrow’ key
      myPhi-=0.01;
    break;

    case 37: // ’up arrow’ key
      myZeta+=0.01;
    break;
    // right
    
    case 39: // ’down arrow’ key
      myZeta-=0.01;
    break;

    break;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);
}

function initWebGL() {
    
  gl = getWebGLContext();
    
  if (!gl) {
    alert("WebGL 2.0 no está disponible");
    return;
  }
  document.onkeydown = handleKeyDown;
  initShaders();
  initPrimitives();
  initRendering();
  initHandlers();
  
  requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);
  
}

initWebGL();
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<script id="myVertexShader" 
      type="x-shader/x-vertex">#version 300 es

  uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
  uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;

  in vec3 VertexPosition;

  void main()  {

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0);

  }

</script>

<script id="myFragmentShader" 
      type="x-shader/x-fragment">#version 300 es

    // Shader de fragmentos

    precision mediump float;
    uniform vec4 myColor;
    out vec4 fragmentColor;

    void main() {

      fragmentColor = myColor;

    }

</script>

<br>
<strong>Phi: </strong><span id="Phi"></span>&deg;
<br>
<strong>Zeta: </strong><span id="Zeta"></span>&deg;
<br>
<strong>Fovy: </strong><span id="Fovy"></span>&deg;
<br>
<strong>Radius: </strong><span id="Radius"></span>
<br>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600">
  El Navegador no soporta HTML5
</canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gl-matrix@3.3.0/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing I did once I got your code to run is add in [webgl-lint](https://greggman.github.io/webgl-helpers/) with

```
<script src="https://greggman.github.io/webgl-lint/webgl-lint.js" crossorigin></script>
```

That immediately brought up this error in the JavaScript console

> webgl-lint.js:2163 Uncaught Error: https://greggman.github.io/webgl-lint/webgl-lint.js:2942: error in uniformMatrix4fv(undefined, false, [0.05000000074505806, 0, 0, 0, 0, -4.5621650389774436e-26, 0.05000000074505806, 0, 0, -0.30000001192092896, -7.29946406236391e-25, 0, -0.30000001192092896, 0.05000000074505806, -4.300000190734863, 1]): argument 0 is undefined
> at reportError (VM9 webgl-lint.js:2163)
> at reportFunctionError (VM9 webgl-lint.js:2924)
> at checkArgs (VM9 webgl-lint.js:2942)
> at WebGL2RenderingContext.ctx. [as uniformMatrix4fv] (VM9 webgl-lint.js:3016)
> at start_draw (js:417)
> at drawall (js:428)
> at drawScene (js:435)\

clicking the first stack trace line related to your code brought me here

```
      // 2. establece la matriz modelMatrix en el shader de vértices
      console.log(finalProj);
--->  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.modelViewMatrix, false, finalProj);
```

It's not `program.modelMatrixIndex` it's `program.modelViewMatrixIndex`

and that got something on the screen

```js
const {mat4} = glMatrix;

var examplePlane = {  // 4 vértices, 2 triángulos

    "vertices" : [-0.5, 0.0, 0.5,
                   0.5, 0.0, 0.5,
                   0.5, 0.0,-0.5,
                  -0.5, 0.0,-0.5],
    
    "indices" : [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3]

};
  
var exampleCube = {  // 8 vértices, 12 triángulos
    
    "vertices" : [-0.5,-0.5,  0.5,
                   0.5,-0.5,  0.5,
                   0.5, 0.5,  0.5,
                  -0.5, 0.5,  0.5,
                  -0.5,-0.5, -0.5,
                   0.5,-0.5, -0.5,
                   0.5, 0.5, -0.5,
                  -0.5, 0.5, -0.5],

    "indices" : [ 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 
                  1, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2,
                  3, 2, 6, 3, 6, 7,
                  5, 4, 7, 5, 7, 6,
                  4, 0, 3, 4, 3, 7,
                  4, 5, 1, 4, 1, 0]

};

var exampleCover = {  // 13 vértices, 12 triángulos

    "vertices" : [ 1,  0, 0,  0.866,  0.5,   0,  0.5,    0.866, 0, 
                   0,  1, 0, -0.5,    0.866, 0, -0.86,   0.5,   0, 
                  -1,  0, 0, -0.866, -0.5,   0, -0.5,   -0.866, 0, 
                   0, -1, 0,  0.5,   -0.866, 0,  0.866, -0.5,   0, 
                   0,  0, 0],
                     
    "indices" : [ 0, 1, 12, 1, 2, 12, 2, 3, 12, 3,  4, 12,  4,  5, 12,  5, 6, 12,  
                  6, 7, 12, 7, 8, 12, 8, 9, 12, 9, 10, 12, 10, 11, 12, 11, 0, 12]

};

var exampleCone = {  // 13 vértices, 12 triángulos

    "vertices" : [ 1,  0, 0,  0.866,  0.5,   0,  0.5,    0.866, 0, 
                   0,  1, 0, -0.5,    0.866, 0, -0.86,   0.5,   0, 
                  -1,  0, 0, -0.866, -0.5,   0, -0.5,   -0.866, 0, 
                   0, -1, 0,  0.5,   -0.866, 0,  0.866, -0.5,   0, 
                   0,  0, 1],
                     
    "indices" : [ 0, 1, 12, 1, 2, 12, 2, 3, 12, 3,  4, 12,  4,  5, 12,  5, 6, 12,  
                  6, 7, 12, 7, 8, 12, 8, 9, 12, 9, 10, 12, 10, 11, 12, 11, 0, 12]

};
                    
var exampleCylinder = {  // 24 vértices, 24 triángulos

    "vertices" : [ 1,  0, 0,  0.866,  0.5,   0,  0.5,    0.866, 0, 
                   0,  1, 0, -0.5,    0.866, 0, -0.86,   0.5,   0, 
                  -1,  0, 0, -0.866, -0.5,   0, -0.5,   -0.866, 0, 
                   0, -1, 0,  0.5,   -0.866, 0,  0.866, -0.5,   0,
                   1,  0, 1,  0.866,  0.5,   1,  0.5,    0.866, 1, 
                   0,  1, 1, -0.5,    0.866, 1, -0.86,   0.5,   1, 
                  -1,  0, 1, -0.866, -0.5,   1, -0.5,   -0.866, 1, 
                   0, -1, 1,  0.5,   -0.866, 1,  0.866, -0.5,   1],
    
    "indices" : [ 0,  1, 12, 1,  2, 13, 2,  3, 14,  3,  4, 15,  4,  5, 16,  5,  6, 17,  
                  6,  7, 18, 7,  8, 19, 8,  9, 20,  9, 10, 21, 10, 11, 22, 11,  0, 23,
                  1, 13, 12, 2, 14, 13, 3, 15, 14,  4, 16, 15,  5, 17, 16,  6, 18, 17,
                  7, 19, 18, 8, 20, 19, 9, 21, 20, 10, 22, 21, 11, 23, 22,  0, 12, 23]

};
           
var exampleSphere = {  // 42 vértices, 80 triángulos

    "vertices" : [ 0.000000, 0.850651, 0.525731,
                  -0.309017, 0.500000, 0.809017,
                   0.309017, 0.500000, 0.809017,
                  -0.525731, 0.000000, 0.850651,
                   0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000,
                   0.525731, 0.000000, 0.850651,
                  -0.850651, 0.525731, 0.000000,
                  -0.809017, 0.309017, 0.500000,
                  -0.500000, 0.809017, 0.309017,
                   0.000000, 0.850651,-0.525731,
                  -0.500000, 0.809017,-0.309017,
                   0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000,
                   0.500000, 0.809017,-0.309017,
                   0.500000, 0.809017, 0.309017,
                   0.850651, 0.525731, 0.000000,
                   0.809017, 0.309017, 0.500000,
                   0.850651,-0.525731, 0.000000,
                   1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                   0.809017,-0.309017, 0.500000,
                   0.525731, 0.000000,-0.850651,
                   0.809017, 0.309017,-0.500000,
                   0.809017,-0.309017,-0.500000,
                   0.309017, 0.500000,-0.809017,
                  -0.525731, 0.000000,-0.850651,
                  -0.309017, 0.500000,-0.809017,
                   0.000000, 0.000000,-1.000000,
                   0.000000,-0.850651,-0.525731,
                  -0.309017,-0.500000,-0.809017,
                   0.309017,-0.500000,-0.809017,
                   0.500000,-0.809017,-0.309017,
                   0.000000,-0.850651, 0.525731,
                   0.000000,-1.000000, 0.000000,
                   0.500000,-0.809017, 0.309017,
                  -0.850651,-0.525731, 0.000000,
                  -0.500000,-0.809017,-0.309017,
                  -0.500000,-0.809017, 0.309017,
                  -0.809017,-0.309017, 0.500000,
                  -0.309017,-0.500000, 0.809017,
                   0.309017,-0.500000, 0.809017,
                  -1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
                  -0.809017,-0.309017,-0.500000,
                  -0.809017, 0.309017,-0.500000],

    "indices" : [ 1, 2, 0, 4, 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 4, 2, 1, 7, 8, 6, 1, 7, 3, 8, 1, 0, 1, 8, 7,10,11, 9, 8,10, 6,
                 11, 8, 0, 8,11,10,11,12, 9,13,11, 0,12,13,14,13,12,11,13,15,14, 2,13, 0,15, 2, 5, 2,15,13,
                 17,18,16,15,17,14,18,15, 5,15,18,17,20,21,19,17,20,14,21,17,16,17,21,20,22,20,19,12,22, 9,
                 20,12,14,12,20,22,24,25,23,22,24, 9,25,22,19,22,25,24,27,28,26,25,27,23,28,25,19,25,28,27,
                 29,21,16,28,29,26,21,28,19,28,21,29,31,32,30,29,31,26,32,29,16,29,32,31,34,35,33,31,34,26,
                 35,31,30,31,35,34,36,37, 3,35,36,33,37,35,30,35,37,36, 4,38, 5,37, 4, 3,38,37,30,37,38, 4,
                 38,18, 5,32,38,30,18,32,16,32,18,38, 7,36, 3,39, 7, 6,36,39,33,39,36, 7,39,40,33,41,39, 6,
                 40,41,23,41,40,39,41,24,23,10,41, 6,24,10, 9,10,24,41,27,40,23,34,27,26,40,34,33,34,40,27]

};

function makeTorus (innerRadius, outerRadius, nSides, nRings) {
        
  var torus = {
      "vertices" : [],
      "indices"  : []
  };
  
  if (nSides < 3 ) nSides = 3;
  if (nRings < 3 ) nRings = 3;
        
  var dpsi =  2.0 * Math.PI / nRings ;
  var dphi = -2.0 * Math.PI / nSides ;
  var psi  =  0.0;
  
  for (var j = 0; j < nRings; j++) {
    
    var cpsi = Math.cos ( psi ) ;
    var spsi = Math.sin ( psi ) ;
    var phi  = 0.0;

    for (var i = 0; i < nSides; i++) {
      
      var offset = 3 * ( j * (nSides+1) + i ) ;
      var cphi   = Math.cos ( phi ) ;
      var sphi   = Math.sin ( phi ) ;
      
      torus.vertices[offset + 0] = cpsi * ( outerRadius + cphi * innerRadius ) ;
      torus.vertices[offset + 1] = spsi * ( outerRadius + cphi * innerRadius ) ;
      torus.vertices[offset + 2] =                        sphi * innerRadius   ;
      
      phi += dphi;
      
    }

    var offset = torus.vertices.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      torus.vertices[offset + i] = torus.vertices[offset-nSides*3+i];

    psi += dpsi;
    
  }

  var offset = torus.vertices.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < 3*(nSides+1); i++)
    torus.vertices[offset+i] = torus.vertices[i];

  for (var j = 0; j < nRings; j++){
    
    var desp = j * (nSides + 1);

    for (var i = 0; i < nSides; i++){
      
      torus.indices.push(desp + i,     desp + i + 1,              desp + i + (nSides+1)); 
      torus.indices.push(desp + i + 1, desp + i + (nSides+1) + 1, desp + i + (nSides+1)); 
      
    }
    
  }

  return torus; 
  
}


var gl, program;
var myTorus;
var myZeta = 0.0, myPhi = Math.PI/2.0, radius = 1.4, fovy = 1.4;

function getWebGLContext() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

  try {
    return canvas.getContext("webgl2",{antialias:true});
  }
  catch(e) {
  }

  return null;

}

function initShaders() {
    
  var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, document.getElementById("myVertexShader").text);
  gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
    return null;
  }
 
  var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, document.getElementById("myFragmentShader").text);
  gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
    return null;
  }
  
  program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  
  gl.linkProgram(program);
    
  gl.useProgram(program);
  idMyColor = gl.getUniformLocation (program, "myColor" );
  program.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "VertexPosition");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.vertexPositionAttribute);

  program.modelViewMatrixIndex  = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"modelViewMatrix");
  program.projectionMatrixIndex = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"projectionMatrix");

}

function initRendering() {

  gl.clearColor(0.95,0.95,0.95,1.0);
  gl.lineWidth(1.5);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

}

function initBuffers(model) {
    
  model.idBufferVertices = gl.createBuffer ();
  gl.bindBuffer (gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, model.idBufferVertices);
  gl.bufferData (gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(model.vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    
  model.idBufferIndices = gl.createBuffer ();
  gl.bindBuffer (gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.idBufferIndices);
  gl.bufferData (gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(model.indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

}

function draw(model) {
  console.log(model);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, model.idBufferVertices);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.idBufferIndices);
  for (var i = 0; i < model.indices.length; i += 3)
    // Si paint es true vol dir que volem pintar per tant farem el triangle_fan

    gl.drawElements (gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 3, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, i*2);
}

// set projection (apliquem una projecció al dibuix)
function setProjection() {
    
  // obtiene la matriz de transformación de la proyección perspectiva
  var projectionMatrix  = mat4.create();
  // perspective
  mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix, Math.PI/4.0, 1., 0.1, 100.0);
  
  // envía la matriz de transformación de la proyección al shader de vértices
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.projectionMatrixIndex,false,projectionMatrix);
}

function initPrimitives() {

  initBuffers(examplePlane);
  initBuffers(exampleCube);
  initBuffers(exampleCover);
  initBuffers(exampleCone);
  initBuffers(exampleCylinder);
  initBuffers(exampleSphere);

  myTorus = makeTorus(0.4, 1.0, 8, 12);
  initBuffers(myTorus);
  
}

function getCameraMatrix() {
  // coordenadas esféricas a rectangulares: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system
  var x = radius * Math.sin(myPhi) * Math.sin(myZeta);
  var y = radius * Math.cos(myPhi);
  var z = radius * Math.sin(myPhi) * Math.cos(myZeta);

  return mat4.lookAt(mat4.create(), [x, y, z], [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]);
    
}


////////////////////
// move the Eye
////////////////////
var eye = [0, 0, 1.4];
var center = [0, 0, 0];

function moveEye () {
    
    return mat4.lookAt(mat4.create(), eye,  center, [0, 1, 0]);
}
///////////////////
///////////////////

function start_draw(model, rx, ry, rz, r1x, r1y, r1z, sx, sy, sz, tx, ty, tz, c1, c2, c3, c4){
  
  // 1. calcula la matriz de transformación
  var modelMatrix = mat4.create();
  var rotationmatr = mat4.create();
  var rotation2 = mat4.create();
  var transmatr = mat4.create();
  var scalematr = mat4.create();

  mat4.fromRotation (rotationmatr, Math.PI/2, [rx, ry, rz]);
  mat4.fromRotation (rotation2, Math.PI/2, [r1x, r1y, r1z]);
  mat4.fromScaling (scalematr, [sx, sy, sz]);
  mat4.multiply (modelMatrix, rotationmatr, rotation2);
  mat4.fromTranslation(transmatr,[tx, ty, tz]);
  mat4.multiply(modelMatrix, transmatr, modelMatrix);
  mat4.multiply(modelMatrix, modelMatrix, scalematr);

  var modelMatrixM     = mat4.create();
  var modelViewMatrixM = mat4.create();
  mat4.fromScaling(modelMatrixM, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]);

  mat4.multiply(modelViewMatrixM, moveEye(), modelMatrixM);
  mat4.multiply(modelViewMatrixM, getCameraMatrix(), modelViewMatrixM);

  var finalProj = mat4.create();
  mat4.multiply(finalProj, modelViewMatrixM, modelMatrix);

  // 2. establece la matriz modelMatrix en el shader de vértices
  console.log(finalProj);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.modelViewMatrixIndex, false, finalProj);

  gl.uniform4f (idMyColor, c1, c2, c3, c4);
  setProjection();
  draw(model);

}

function drawall(){


  start_draw(exampleCylinder, .5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, .1, .1, .6, -.6, .1, -3, .5, 0, .5, .7);
  
}

function drawScene() {
    
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  drawall();

}

function initHandlers() {
    
  var mouseDown = false;
  var lastMouseX;
  var lastMouseY;

  var canvas     = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var htmlPhi    = document.getElementById("Phi");
  var htmlZeta   = document.getElementById("Zeta");
  var htmlRadius = document.getElementById("Radius");
  var htmlFovy   = document.getElementById("Fovy");

  htmlPhi.innerHTML    = (myPhi  * 180 / Math.PI).toFixed(1);
  htmlZeta.innerHTML   = (myZeta * 180 / Math.PI).toFixed(1);
  htmlRadius.innerHTML = radius.toFixed(1);
  htmlFovy.innerHTML   = (fovy * 180 / Math.PI).toFixed(1);

 
  canvas.addEventListener("wheel",
    function (event) {
      
      var delta = 0.0;

      if (event.deltaMode == 0)
        delta = event.deltaY * 0.001;
      else if (event.deltaMode == 1)
        delta = event.deltaY * 0.03;
      else
        delta = event.deltaY;

      if (event.shiftKey == 1) { // fovy
          
        fovy *= Math.exp(-delta)
        fovy = Math.max (0.1, Math.min(3.0, fovy));
        
        htmlFovy.innerHTML = (fovy * 180 / Math.PI).toFixed(1);
        
      } else {
        
        radius *= Math.exp(-delta);
        radius  = Math.max(Math.min(radius, 30), 0.05);
        
        htmlRadius.innerHTML = radius.toFixed(1);
        
      }
      
      event.preventDefault();
      requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);

    }, false);
  
}        

function handleKeyDown(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
  switch (event.keyCode) {

    //MOVEMENT
    case 87: // ’w’ key
        eye[2] -= 0.01;
        center[2] -=0.01;
      break;
      // right
    case 83: // ’s’ key
      eye[2] += 0.01;
      center[2] +=0.01;

      break;
    case 65: // ’a’ key
      eye[0] -= 0.01;
      center[0] -=0.01;

      break;
      // right
    case 68: // ’d’ key
      eye[0] += 0.01;
      center[0] +=0.01;
      break;

    //CAMERA MOVEMENT
    case 38: // ’up arrow’ key
      myPhi+=0.01;
    break;
    // right
    
    case 40: // ’down arrow’ key
      myPhi-=0.01;
    break;

    case 37: // ’up arrow’ key
      myZeta+=0.01;
    break;
    // right
    
    case 39: // ’down arrow’ key
      myZeta-=0.01;
    break;

    break;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);
}

function initWebGL() {
    
  gl = getWebGLContext();
    
  if (!gl) {
    alert("WebGL 2.0 no está disponible");
    return;
  }
  document.onkeydown = handleKeyDown;
  initShaders();
  initPrimitives();
  initRendering();
  initHandlers();
  
  requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);
  
}

initWebGL();
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<script id="myVertexShader" 
      type="x-shader/x-vertex">#version 300 es

  uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
  uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;

  in vec3 VertexPosition;

  void main()  {

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0);

  }

</script>
<script id="myFragmentShader" 
      type="x-shader/x-fragment">#version 300 es

    // Shader de fragmentos

    precision mediump float;
    uniform vec4 myColor;
    out vec4 fragmentColor;

    void main() {

      fragmentColor = myColor;

    }

</script>

<br>
<strong>Phi: </strong><span id="Phi"></span>&deg;
<br>
<strong>Zeta: </strong><span id="Zeta"></span>&deg;
<br>
<strong>Fovy: </strong><span id="Fovy"></span>&deg;
<br>
<strong>Radius: </strong><span id="Radius"></span>
<br>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600">
  El Navegador no soporta HTML5
</canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gl-matrix@3.3.0/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
```

PS: Please learn how to use [snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) and CDNs for libraries

Also, just FYI, `getContext` never throws so this code

```
function getWebGLContext() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

  try {
    return canvas.getContext("webgl2",{antialias:true});
  }
  catch(e) {
  }

  return null;

}
```

makes no sense. It should just be

```
function getWebGLContext() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  return canvas.getContext("webgl2",{antialias:true});
}
```

and further, `antialias: true` is the default so

```
function getWebGLContext() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  return canvas.getContext("webgl2");
}
```